# Is there a way where I can serve static files in one path

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I am trying to learn backend, so my goal is to learn how to serve static files for example I have folder named public it contains three files /index.html,style.css,script.js things are working good so far how ever when I pass the /style.css to the route of home path I am getting the contents of the style.css even with javascript so how can I prevent that from happening while everthing works as expected, please keep in mind that all this should be implemented on url of localhost:3030, so my goal is that when I type that to the url I want to see the html and its style applied thank you. No libraries or frameworks needed.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    // Map requested URL to a file path
    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url);
    
    if (req.url === '/') {
        filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html');
    }
    
    // Determine the content type based on the file extension
    const extname = path.extname(filePath);
    console.log(extname)
    let contentType = 'text/html';

    if (extname === '.css') {
        contentType = 'text/css';
    } else if (extname === '.js') {
        contentType = 'text/javascript';
    }

    // Read and serve the file
    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                // File not found, return a 404 response
                res.statusCode = 404;
                res.end('File not found');
            } else {
                // Other error, return a 500 response
                res.statusCode = 500;
                res.end('Internal Server Error');
            }
        } else {
            // Set content type and serve the file
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
            res.end(data);
        }
    });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3030;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`http://localhost:${PORT}`);

});
```

Comment: Your best using some lib that has routing, express is a popular one..

Comment: Not just "a popular one", it's the standard. Start using [express](https://expressjs.com/) and use its `express.static` functionality for static assets. It'll take care of all the server headers, mimetypes, etc.

Comment: I have decided to stay away frameworks or libs at all cost only something that is enterprise maybe.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to prevent something or to allow something? You wrote that everything works. In addition, Express won't solve this problem. This code already implements the expected functionality.

Comment: What is the problem with "... how ever when I pass the /style.css to the route of home path I am getting the contents of the style.css ...". Is that not what the server is supposed to do?

Comment: I think what you aren't getting is that the HTML page must reference the CSS, not the other way around.

Comment: I've created a minimal example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rzavzf?file=package.json Everything works as it should. The question is unclear. The CSS style is applied and the JavaScript script is evaluated.

Comment: Are you trying to hide the code of the files? That's not possible. The best you can do is to obfuscate it.

Answer (score -2):

Check out https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static/blob/master/lib/node-static.js for the proper implementation of serving the files on one path

Comment: Please don't post a link to an external answer. Post the answer as text.